# Grabbing the 'ID' from the name of the object in JSON

Tags: php, json

I found a JSON dump of items for a game I play

> - http://mooshe.pw/files/items_rs3.json

I want to be able to search/find the item's id by searching/inputting the name.

ex: Search 'dwarf remains' and get the number 0 returned (does the name need to be case sensitive and if so can I make it so it isn't?)

So far all I have is this

```
$itemName = $_GET['name'];
```

But once I have the name, I don't know how to convert it to the id number prefixing the object which I need

Edit: Sorry for not being so clear - my end goal is to be able to input a 'name' of an item, and I then need to convert the name to the ID (?) that prefixes the relevant object so I can then pass it on to an API and gather stats etc.

How would I convert the name to the ID e.g. Dwarf remains to 0?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is your script actually going to be reading that file or are you treating it as a static string?

Comment: You can use [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) to remove the case sensitive part. The easiest code to write would be to loop the json array/object and compare the name until you get a result

Comment: I'm guessing it will have to read the JSON file yes. Sorry for not being so clear - my end goal is to be able to input a 'name' of the item, and I then need to convert the name to the ID (?) that prefixes the relevant object so I can then pass it on to an API and gather stats etc.

Comment: what do you mean by "prefixes" ? without having a data sample to work with, it's impossible to guess what you are referring to.

Comment: Unfortunately, if all you really have is `$itemName = $_GET['name'];`, then you're not even close to being at the point where a question here is appropriate.  We can't write the whole thing for you, and at this point, that's basically what you're asking for.

Comment: I have the name, I'm just trying to find out the relevant steps to now take the name and match it to the ID as I have no idea how to go about it, even in pseudo

Comment: Right, so you need to learn basic coding. Do some research on opening and reading files, dealing with JSON data, checking for values in arrays, etc.  As it stands, your question is too broad is could potentially get closed.